# Sending JWT back as query string after google oauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js, google-oauth

What is the best way for sending JWT after user get authenticated by google oauth?

I'm currently using node/express as backend and react as frontend (they are on different domains).

One way is setting the token as a query string and redirect to react.

Express router:

```
router.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);
router.get(
    '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/', session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        const token = req.user.token;
        res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000?token=${token}`);
    }
);
```

App.js in react:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    if (query.token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', query.token);
      this.props.history.push('/');
   }
}
render(){
   ...
}
```

Is sending token as query string safe?

Is there any better way for this?

Comment: hey, i am searching best way this case. did you find good way?

Comment: @JeongkukSeo It's a bad practice to send back token as a query string, so I ended up using the following react component:  
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login